# Format google Form answer to be text instead of number?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a numbering system that works as per the following structure: 000A00 (where the first three digits represent the day number of the year, the "A" represents a year letter (I am currently on year "E") and the last two digits represent a revision number of the product.

This number is submitted as an answer in a google form. However, we have run into an issue with the current year letter being "E"... because now instead of the answer being seen as text (as I want), it thinks it is a number with scientific notation. **So instead of 015E01, for instance, it is converted to 1.50E+02 and that is what is displayed in the response sheet.** Any suggestions for how to **get it to rather display as the original text??**

I have tried changing the format of the corresponding column. If you change the format to plain text and then type in the text on the Sheet, then it stays as the text. However, when a Form submission occurs, it seems that a row is inserted and does not take on the format of the column. Changing the format after the fact also doesn't seem to work to revert it to the original text.

Suggestions are welcome, including a script to solve it. However, please keep in mind that I am running a couple of hundred Forms like this, with each one having a few questions requiring this type of response structure and the amount of questions and question numbers (and corresponding columns in the response sheets) changes in each form.

This is obviously only an issue with it now being the year letter as "E" and I have hundreds of entries from previous years that have all worked just fine.

Comment: The simplest solution might be to have an extra column in your Responses sheet that forced a conversion to text - but you don't want to do that for hundreds of forms.  Then possibly an onFormSubmit script to force that conversion, but even deploying that to hundreds of forms could be time consuming.  Lastly, a script that reads through all of your Response sheets, and adds the conversion column to them?  But if the columns change in each form, that could also be challenging to automate - are your date columns/fields are identifiable by name, else search by content?  Just throwing out ideas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to duplicate your issue and create a script that might point you in the right direction. See my [example form here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe4c-c8Mxi0nEFy_WSw4edNRlxotypvfe2pYxcMlMO_3fK3lA/viewform) and the [corresponding spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jEe8WtDQt8zScFcuN3F3mlRVmTjUGwOdhTuTYwAb9K0/edit?usp=sharing). The highlighted column shows modified response values being sent from the form (feel free to test by sending in fake entries).

All it's doing is taking the form response value to the specific item (Which is as text) and then just insert it as text formula such as `="015E01"`.

Here's the code I used which includes updating for all entries, and also if you wanted to try to adjust retroactive members. Make sure to update your code with the appropriate spreadsheet ID and constants in the header.

```
const thisForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
const theQuestion = thisForm.getItemById(21944463) //<--- change this to your question number
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(thisForm.getDestinationId()).getActiveSheet();
//runs on submissiong
  //Make sure to enable as a trigger
  function onEntry(e) {
    addTextValue(e.response);
  }

//fixes all responses
function fixAllValues() {
const entryPoint = "E2"; //set where you want to insert new values
var theCollectedReplies = [];
var allReplies = thisForm.getResponses();
for (var i = 0; i < allReplies.length; i++) {

  var theValue = allReplies[i].getResponseForItem(theQuestion).getResponse();
  theCollectedReplies.push(['"' + theValue + '"']);
}
ss.getRange(ss.getRange(entryPoint).getRow(), ss.getRange(entryPoint).getColumn(), 
  theCollectedReplies.length, 1).setFormulasR1C1(theCollectedReplies);
}


//Add values when resposnses are submited
  function addTextValue(theResponse) {
    const theColumnOfData = 4 //where to put new entry
    var theValue = theResponse.getResponseForItem(theQuestion).getResponse();

    ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), theColumnOfData).setFormulaR1C1('"' + theValue + '"');
  }
```

Comment: This is great and has already helped me quite a bit. I didn't even know one could make the sheet ID dynamic by getting it as the form destination sheet. The only problem with this is that it creates a new column rather than overwriting the data in the answer column. Essentially I never want it to have the "wrong" data anywhere on the sheet. These sheets are used by a database system and would cause errors by having this scientific notation instead of the "text number". I guess I can just try point to the col number of the original answer and see if it overwrites. I'll play a bit.

Comment: Also still going to be hard to implement I guess... because of each Form having various questions needing this to be implemented (would have to identify question numbers for each form). Converting ALL the answers to text might work, but again need it to overwrite the answer in sheet rather than create new columns. Some answers are actual numbers and not sure converting those to text would cause issues on the database but it might not.

Comment: onEntry(e) didn't seem to run as a simple trigger? I have never really used simple triggers though, so not sure if I am missing something though. I just added a manual trigger to run that function on "form submit"...but then surely one can just ignore that function and rather just trigger the addTextValue function? I think I am missing something here though.

Comment: @PGSystemTester  may I know how to get the question number?

Comment: @Kelvin `.getItemId()` or post your question as include the link here.