# Google Apps Script - force setValue to text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I am using setValue() to put values from an array into spreadsheet cells. Some array elements contain data that is text, but is being parsed as numeric, eg: "6E5", and setValue() converts them (in that case the cell gets the numeric value 600000). Is there any way to force the cell to be a text value?

Comment: If you are putting an array of values into a spreadsheet you should consider using setValues()

Comment: You can also use setNumberFormats(); while puts in an array of formats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking to set the number format. Do this before you setValue. See example below. You could also create all of your array values to be a formula. Example `="6E5"` see an answer [I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65740727/11732320) related to forms.

Something like this....

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc*/

function setRangeToBeText() {
  var newValue = [["6E5","7d","99"]];

  //test on first cell
  var theRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,newValue.length,newValue[0].length);

  //sets format first
  theRange.setNumberFormat('@');
  theRange.setValues(newValue);
}
```

**Example setting Format:**
[image]

Example WITHOUT setting format:
[image]]